# Korrekte Interpretationsmöglichkeiten von "dieser Zug fährt weiter als Linie 5"

Tags: sentence-structure

Vor Jahr und Tag hörte ich im Zuge diese Durchsage :

> "Dieser Zug fährt ab M.-Hauptbahnhof weiter als Linie 5 über die Sowiesostraße und ..."

Gemeint war:

> "Dieser Zug fährt ab M.-Hauptbahnhof als Linie 5 weiter über die Sowiesostraße und ...",

Ich sagte jedoch scherzhaft zu meiner Begleiterin "was kümmert es mich, ob er weiter als die Linie 5 fährt?".

Nach meinem Gefühl gibt es nämlich (rein syntaktisch) zwei völlig korrekte Interpretationsmöglichkeiten:

> Dieser Zug fährt ab M.-Hauptbahnhof, weiterhin als Linie 5, über die Sowiesostraße und ...",

er wechselt mithin nicht seine Bezeichnung, was dort häufig vorkam. Oder aber:

> Dieser Zug fährt ab M.-Hauptbahnhof eine weitere Strecke denn die Linie 5, über die Sowiesostraße und ...",

während die beabsichtigte Interpretation eigentlich **nicht** gestattet ist.
**Was gemeint war, wusste wohl jeder, der die Strecke kannte. Ich möchte wissen, ob sich meine (haarspalterische) Sicht anhand syntaktischer Regeln widerlegen lässt.**

Comment: Glaube ich nicht. Mehrdeutige Sätze sind normal, wahrscheinlich ist kaum ein Satz völlig eindeutig.

Comment: Geschrieben ist es zumindest unglücklich. Ich hoffe mal, dass eine entsprechende Betonung oder Sprechpause eine eindeutigere Schlussfolgerung erwarten ließ.

Comment: @hellcode leider war die Betonung sehr missverständlich, aber der praktische Verstand half. Ich frage mich jedoch ob sich mein Standpunkt anhand festgeschriebener Regeln bewerten lässt, oder ob es nicht mehr gibt als unser Bauchgefühl als Muttersprachler!

Comment: Die Doppeldeutigkeit war mir bis gerade entgangen. – Aber ist "weiterhin" nicht falsch in deiner Interpretation? Für gewöhnlich kommt diese Durchsage, wenn die Nummer geändert wird. Daher müsste es lauten: "Dieser Zug fährt ab HBF über blabla, aber als Linie 5."

Comment: @Em1 ich wage da nichts bestimmtes zu sagen. Ich habe nur mein Gefühl. Daher stieß ich die Diskussion an um zu erfahren, was die Regeln dazu sagen. Du hast schon Recht, dass man allgemein nur auf Änderungen hinweisen würde. Wenn sich solche allerdings häufen, kann das Gleichbleiben zur Ausnahme werden.

Comment: @Ludi Die Regeln, nach denen Du suchst, heißen Gricesche Konversationsmaximen. In diesem Fall ist das Kriterium 'Relevanz' einschlägig.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich finde, die Schlüsselfrage ist hier: Wie lautet das Verb?

**a) Das Verb ist *weiterfahren*.**

Das ist in dem Satz (offenbar unstrittig) gemeint. Der Satz lautet im Kern also

> Der Zug fährt weiter.

und wir haben als weitere Satzteile *ab M.-Hauptbahnhof*, *als Linie 5* und *über die Sowiesostraße*. Das ist syntaktisch korrekt - es passt alles hinsichtlich Fall, Geschlecht und Zahl, und was den Satzbau angeht, haben wir es hier mit 3 Präpositionalgruppen zu tun, von denen eine im Hauptfeld steht  und zwei im Nachfeld (oder möglicherweise noch mehr, denn Dein Beispiel ist ja nach hinten offen). Das ist nicht verboten und ein übliches Mittel, um die Satzklammer nicht zu lang werden zu lassen. Siehe dazu die [Erläuterungen bei canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Nachfeld.html#Anchor-14210).

Die von Dir als gültig erachtete Variante

> Dieser Zug fährt ab M.-Hauptbahnhof als Linie 5 weiter über die Sowiesostraße und ...

unterscheidet sich vom Original nur durch die Verschiebung einer Gruppe vom Nach- ins Hauptfeld. Das ist kein Muss.

**b) Das Verb ist *fahren***.

Das ist die zwingende Folge aus Deinen Interpretationen, denn in Ihnen behandelst Du *weiter als Linie 5* als eine Wortgruppe, also kann *weiter* nicht zum Verb gehören. Ohne diese Wortgruppe lautet der Satz dann

> Dieser Zug fährt ab M.-Hauptbahnhof über die Sowiesostraße und ...

Syntaktisch ist dagegen erstmal auch nichts einzuwenden, semantisch würde dann allerdings ein *von* besser passen als das *ab* ("von A über B nach C" - mit *ab* müsste eine Aussage folgen, die für die gesamte Fahrtdauer ab M gültig ist, nicht nur für einen Zwischenhalt).

Wenn Du *weiter* verstehst als Steigerung von *weit*, dann kommt mit *weiter als Linie 5* einfach eine zusätzliche Adverbialbestimmung hinzu - syntaktisch nach wie vor korrekt, aber semantisch wird es noch ein bisschen wilder, wie [Emanuel in seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24496/korrekte-interpretationsm%C3%B6glichkeiten-von-dieser-zug-f%C3%A4hrt-weiter-als-linie-5/24499#24499) ausführlich erklärt hat.

Was hingegen (ganz klar zumindest in der schriftlichen Form) **nicht** geht, ist die Interpretation von *weiter* als *weiterhin*. Denn dann wäre die Wortgruppe eine eingeschobene Erläuterung, die zwingend in Kommas eingeschlossen werden müsste (entsprechend kurzen Pausen in der gesprochenen Form). Das ist festgelegt in [§77.4](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html#pgf77-4) der amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln, in denen es heißt:

> Wird ... die Erläuterung in die substantivische oder verbale Fügung einbezogen, so grenzt man sie mit einfachem Komma ab.

In der [Erläuterung bei canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Zusatz.html#Anchor-Nachgestellte-11481) heißt es dazu:

> Nachgestellte und eingeschobene Erläuterungen werden oft durch *also, besonders, das heißt (d. h.), genauer, insbesondere, nämlich, und zwar, vor allem, zum Beispiel (z. B.)* und ähnliche Wörter oder Ausdrücke eingeleitet.

*Weiter(hin)* wird hier zwar nicht ausdrücklich erwähnt, aber es entspricht in seiner Funktion einem *und zwar* oder *übrigens* und wird deshalb durch die Formulierung "und ähnliche Wörter" bzw. (in der amtlichen Regel) "oder dergleichen" abgedeckt.

Comment: Auch eine sehr schöne Antwort. Syntaktisch sehr erhellend und sehr gut strukturiert über die Wahl des Verbs!

Answer (score 4):

Als ich diese Frage las, war mir nicht sofort klar, dass es andere Interpretationsmöglichkeiten als

> Die Fahrstrecke dieses Zuges reicht weiter als jene von Zügen, die auf der Linie 5 fahren.

geben könnte. Wie ich erst beim Weiterlesen festgestellt habe, war diese Interpretation sogar die falsche. Daher ziehe ich den Satz »*Was gemeint war wusste wohl jeder*« sehr in Zweifel. Ohne Zusatzinformationen hätte ich es nicht gewusst.

Tatsache ist aber, dass die beiden der von dir genannten Interpretationsmöglichkeiten legitim sind.

Ich halte es übrigens durchaus für keine Haarspalterei, sich darüber Gedanken zu machen. Im Gegenteil: Ich halte es von den Verfassern dieses Satzes für fahrlässig, nicht ausreichend auf Eindeutigkeit zu achten. Denn solche Sätze können zu Fehlentscheidungen bei der Reiseplanung von Fahrgästen führen, die wiederum zu einem finanziellen Schaden (falsch gekaufte Fahrkarte) oder zu einer Verspätung führen können.

Comment: Sie haben mal wieder Recht. Es wusste wohl nur jeder, der die Strecke kannte.

Comment: Gibt es denn, neben dem Gefühl des Muttersprachlers, feste Regeln womit wir diese unsere Ansicht belegen können? Ich tue mich immer schwer bei deren Identifikation, was beim Lehren ein gehöriges Manko ist, welches ich durch gute Beispiele zu lindern suche, nicht jedoch ohne mich über meine Schwäche zu ärgern.

Comment: Das »Gefühl des Muttersprachlers« ist in Wahrheit auch nichts anderes als ein komplexer Satz von Regeln, allerdings handelt es sich hier um implizites Wissen, das (noch) nicht in explizite Regeln übertragen wurde. Der einfachste Weg, sich dieses implizite Wissen anzueignen ist Training. Also viel lesen und noch mehr hören, und dabei schreiben und sprechen, wobei hier das Feedback sehr wichtig ist. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implizites_Wissen

Comment: Das ist sicher richtig und ich erkläre Sprache sehr gern mit Beispielen! Aber eine gewisse, recht kleine, Gruppe von Schülern freut sich stets über (offizielle) Regeln :)

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass Deine Fehlinterpretation lediglich daran lag, dass Du zuvor die Überschrift gelesen hattest.

Comment: Der Satz ist sehr eindeutig und im Kontext schwer missverständlich. Zumal die Durchsage meistens kommt, wenn die Liniennummer sich ändert, und der Normalmensch, weiß, dass er nicht in Linie 5 eingestiegen ist. (Alternativ kommt die Durchsage, wenn umgeleitet wird, wobei normalerweise die Liniennummer nicht erwähnt wird, wenn sie sich nicht ändert.)

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt insgesamt drei Möglichkeiten:

> a) Der Zug bleibt Linie 5
>
> b) Der Zug wird zur Linie 5 und fährt weiter
>
> c) Die Strecke, die der Zug ab HB fährt, ist länger als die, die Linie 5 fährt

Version a) kann man ausschließen. Warum?
In dieser Version wäre „weiter als Linie 5“ eine Apposition, durch Komma oder Sprachzäsur getrennt. Das ist in OPs Beispiel nicht der Fall. Zudem würde die Information bei Ansagen wohl nicht extra erwähnt.

Bleiben also b) und c). Syntaktisch lässt sich das nicht klären, wohl aber semantisch/pragmatisch. Ohne Kontext. Version b) ist weit wahrscheinlicher. Warum?
Der Satz enthält ein „ab“.

> Der Zug fährt ab Punkt X weiter als Linie 5 über Punkt B und C.

Wenn man den Satz als Vergleich zweier Linien interpretiert, heißt er, dass sobald Punkt X erreicht ist, der Zug eine weitere Strecke über B und C fährt als Linie 5 (die auch über B und C fährt). Allerdings ist die Art der Formulierung sehr sehr ungewöhnlich. Warum ist die Strecke, die der Zug fährt, erst ab Punkt X länger? Ist sie nicht von Beginn an länger? Klar kann man es so sagen, wenn man ausdrücken will, dass die Strecken vom Zug und Linie 5 bei X auseinanderlaufen, aber komplizierter könnte man das fast gar nicht ausdrücken. Es gibt keinen Grund dafür und viele dagegen, es so zu formulieren. Daher ist die pragmatische Interpretation die, dass es KEIN Vergleich zweier Linien sein kann, denn zwei Dialogpartner sind normalerweise am gegensätzlichen Verstehen interessiert.

Fazit:

Ohne den „ab“-Teil wäre der Satz in der Tat extrem doppeldeutig. Ist er auch so, wenn man will, aber das „ab“ verschiebt die Wahrscheinlichkeiten allerdings sehr von einem Vergleich weg.

Zusatz:

Es gibt auch noch die theoretische Möglichkeit, dass es ein Vergleich ist und Linie 5 NICHT über B und C fährt. Dann wäre die Info, dass der Zug über B und C fährt, allerdings eine neue Informationseinheit und sollte also Apposition meiner Ansicht nach ebenfalls durch Komma oder Gedankenstrich abgetrennt werden.

> Der Zug fährt weiter als Linie 5 ,/- über B und C.

Edit:

Zur Satzstellung – das „weiter“ hat, wenn es denn nicht sogar als eins aufzufassen ist, starken Präfixcharakter. Sein „Standardplatz“ wäre also am Ende der Phrase. Die Infos über die folgenden Zwischenhalte wurden ins Nachfeld gerückt, da sie sehr lang sind. Das ist nix Ungewöhnliches. Bleibt die Frage, ob es okay ist, das „weiter“ noch weiter vorzuziehen. Und die Antwort ist ja. Aktuell gibt es einen starken Trend zur „Clusterung“. Die verbale Phrase mitsamt dem wichtigsten Komplement behält Satzklammercharakter, der Rest wird nach hinten ausgeklammert. Die Medien und auch aktuelle Sachbücher sind voll von sowas.

> Die Initiative BISS stellt sich vor als Alternative zu …

Es gibt Millionen solcher Beispiele. Die Satzstellung in der Ansage ist also durchaus en vogue.

Comment: Gefällt mir. Du könntest noch etwas über Satzstellungsvarianten schreiben (z.B. mit Verweis auf http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Nachfeld.html#Anchor-14210), um explizit die Annahme in der Frage zu widerlegen, dass die beabsichtigte Interpretation (also b) nicht gestattet sei.

Comment: @Matthias... hab was ergänzt. Weiß nicht, ob es das ist, was du meinst.

Comment: "Version a) kann man ausschließen." - ja, aber nicht aus dem genannten Grund. Da "weiter" mitunter auch synonym zu "weiterhin" verwendet wird, wäre mit dieser Bedeutung zwischen "weiter" und "als Linie 5" eben *kein* Komma und auch keine sonstige Trennung angebracht. Man kann Version a) allerdings in der realen Situation tendenziell ausschließen, wenn das, was gerade einfährt oder hält, eben nicht die Linie 5 ist.

Comment: Zu Version a): ich sehe es wie @O.R.Mapper und finde hier Kommata außerdem irrelevant, weil es eine schlecht betonte Ansage war - oder die Betonung am ehesten c) nahelegte. Ich wusste sofort was gemeint war, musste aber intensiv an Interpretation c) denken und zwar in der Variante des Zusatzes. Sehr schöne Antwort. Besonders interessierten mich allerdings etwaige syntaktische Regeln.

Comment: @Matthias Jawohl, an so einer Widerlegung wäre ich interessiert. Wie würde sie aussehen, bezogen auf die konkreten Regeln? Semantisch wurde ja schon sehr schön gearbeitet!

Answer (score 2):

Ich wäre nie auf die Idee gekommen, den Satz anders zu interpretieren, als er von der Verkehrsgesellschaft gedacht war. Das hat allerdings aus meiner Sicht einen Grund, der noch viel einfacher ist, als die langen und breiten Erklärungen, die andere Leute schon gegeben haben.

Du unterstellst, dass der Satz aussagen könnte, dass der weitere Linienweg der Tram länger sei, als derjenige der Linie 5. Dabei hast du laut Frage eine scherzhafte Bemerkung gemacht, die genau den Kern des Problems trifft.

> Was kümmert es mich, ob er weiter **als die** Linie 5 fährt?

(Hervorhebung von mir)

Meines Erachtens kannst du die beiden Linienwege und deren Länge nur vergleichen, wen du den ursprünglichen Satz ebenfalls mit bestimmtem Artikel formulierst:

> Dieser Zug fährt ab Hauptbahnhof weiter **als die** Linie 5 …

Denn schließlich ist die Linie 5 etwas Bestimmtes; ihr Linienweg ist festgelegt und wird beim Fahrgast als bekannt vorausgesetzt, sonst könnte man ihn nicht mit dem Linienweg der Tram, in der du dich befindest, vergleichen. Weglassen des Artikels unterstellt – ein vergleichendes *als* angenommen –, dass »Linie 5« ein Eigenname sei. Das mit einer Trambahnlinie in Verbindung zu bringen geht meines Erachtens nur, wenn »Linie 5« eine historisch gewachsene Bezeichnung ist, während die Tramlinien heutzutage zwei- oder dreistellige Nummern (qua Verkehrsverbund oder dergleichen) haben.

---

In dem Zusammenhang verweise ich auch auf die Formulierung, die die Braunschweiger Verkehrs-AG verwendet, und die noch besser jedes Missverständnis ausschließt:

> Bitte beachten Sie, dass dieser Omnibus **weiterfährt** als Linie 411 in Richtung Hauptbahnhof.

Comment: Auch ein guter Punkt!

Comment: Schriebs, saß in einer Tram und hört den Satz »Diese Straßenbahn **fährt weiter** als Linie 4 zur Helmstedter Straße« ;D

Comment: Man möchte anmerken, dass dies ein weiteres Beispiel ist, wie wichtig die Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibung bestimmter Verben ist (ein Umstand den die sogenannte Rechtschreibreform so sträflich missachtete): a) Beachten Sie, dass dieser Bus **weiterfährt** als Linie 411. [= umbenannt als bzw. in Funktion von Linie 411] b) Bitte beachten Sie, dass dieser Bus **weiter fährt** als Linie 411. [= über den Endhaltepunkt der Linie 411 hinaus]